# My CSS style sheet only affected 3 out of my 4 pages. How do I update that 4th page?

Tags: html, css, transition

My main problem here is that I have one .css stylesheet hooked up to 3 page because this really is just forming a template for the time being until I can decide how I want each page to look individually.

I preformed some div positioning on the website and I think it looks nice and centered on most of the pages...most. I have one page that is hooked up to the correct style sheet and will change anything I add to the style sheet, except where some divs won't shift on this one page. Here is a screenshot of a page that works:

[image: a working example]
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chyqb.jpg)

And one that doesn't:
[image: a non-working example]
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK7jD.jpg)

If you look closely, you are can see that my links are shifted more to the upper-right corner and so are my main content sections. The other two links that are used in this website look the same as the working page, by the way.

CODING (Warning, there may be a tad unnecessary code there, but the coding is exactly the same on all websites except for the img src attributes, so there is no reason that all page wouldn't look the same):

Page that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Teens For Antarctica Preservation</title>
<link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <p><a id="firstlink" href="index.html">TAP</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="whatis.html">Who is TAP</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="why.html">Why we do it</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="resources.html">Resources</a></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img id="image" src="images/14_Seal2.jpg" /> <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="main="Main" content="Content"" --><p id="main">Main Content</p>

<div id="footer"><p id="pfoot" style="vertical-align:bottom;">Teenspace and Teens For Antartica Preservation Inc. <br />Web Desinger: Mathew Crogan</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for the website that doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Who is TAP?</title>
<link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
<div>
  <p><a id="firstlink" href="index.html">TAP</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="whatis.html">Who is TAP</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="why.html">Why we do it</a>
    <a id="rollover" href="resources.html">Resources</a></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<img src="images/14_Teens.jpg" id="image"/><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="main="Main" content="Content"" --><p id="main">Main Content</p>

<div id="footer"><p id="pfoot" style="vertical-align:bottom;">Teenspace and Teens For Antartica Preservation Inc. <br />Web Desinger: Mathew Crogan</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS stylesheet:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.header
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

html
{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color:#D7D7FF;
}

    a#rollover:link, a#rollover:visited
{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#B8B8B8;
width:120px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
margin-top:30px;
}

a#rollover:hover, a#rollover:active
{
background-color:#A7A7A7;
}

a#firstlink:link, a#firstlink:visited
{
    display:block;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#B8B8B8;
width:120px;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid #000;
float:left;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:265px;
}

a#firstlink:hover, a#firstlink:active
{
    background-color:#A7A7A7;
}

#image
{
    height:230px; 
    width:300px; 
    float:left; 
    border: 3px solid #B5B5B5; 
    margin-left:150px; 
    margin-top:10px;
    border-radius:25px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 6px #A3A3A3;

}


#main
{
    height:250px; 
    width:450px; 
    border:3px solid #B5B5B5; 
    margin-left:500px; 
    margin-top:15px;
    border-radius:25px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 6px #A3A3A3;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight:400;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#footer
{
    height:100px;
    bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-left:25px;
}

#pfoot
{
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Please provide any insite on how to fix this problem.

Comment: It may not be the cause of your issue, but it's technically invalid HTML to use the same ID on multiple elements.  Try changing your id="rollover" to class="rollover" and the '#rollover' in your CSS to '.rollover'.  That might help.

Comment: if you are using php, you could add a timestamp to the stylesheet forcing it to be reloaded every time a user visits your page

Comment: In `CSS` `ID`s need to be `unique`, you should use reusable `classes` for your `CSS`

Answer (score 4):

Working

```
<div class="header">
   <div style="margin-left:200px;"> 
     <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

Not working

```
<div class="header">
    <div style="margin-left:200px;"> 
        <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
     </div>
```

On the not working version, you've missed out the closing div for 'header'

Answer (score 0):

I see, your html code is not the same.

1st document

```
<body>
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

and the second document:

```
<body>
<div class="header"><div style="margin-left:200px;"> <img src="images/logo_2.jpg" width="600" style="padding-top:12.5px;" />
</div>
<div>
```

the second document is not correct, as you forgot to close the second `div`.